# Run 2 or more scripts in different terminal windows [MAC]

Tags: node.js, macos, bash

I need to run 2 or more scripts in different terminal windows automatically.

Now I have these scripts.

```
script1.command
script2.command
script3.command
```

I need another script that can automatically launch all the 3 scripts in 3 different terminal windows.
How can I do? 
What I try is to create a fourth script like this:

```
script1.command & script2.command & script3.command
```

And it works well except for the fact that it runs all the script in the same window.
Note: each one of the 3 scripts runs a node js server app.

Comment: try this `open -a Terminal.app script1.command & open -a Terminal.app script1.command & open -a Terminal.app script1.command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to open each script in a new terminal like this.

```
open -a Terminal.app script1.command & open -a Terminal.app script1.command & open -a Terminal.app script1.command
```